# HTTP request libraries for Python 3.x

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, python-requests

Consensus seems to be that `requests` is by far the best option for making HTTP requests in Python 2.x. However, in Python 3.x `urllib2` has been "split into parts and renamed to `urllib.request`, `urllib.parse`, and `urllib.error`." Has it just been renamed, or has it had parts rewritten making it a decent alternative to `requests`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urllib` and `urllib2` libraries have been cleaned up for Python 3, moving various disparate parts into a clear package hierarchy. The APIs themselves haven't changed all that much. It's mostly a tightening of the naming conventions.

You only need to compare the [Python 2 `urllib2` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) with the [`urllib.request` page for Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) (with only exceptions moved to [`request.error`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html)) to see that the basic functionality has not been updated.

`requests` itself remains the better choice for handling your HTTP client needs in Python 3.